# Syntax to access json array

Tags: javascript

I don't know the syntax to access the "relatedTo" array of my Json object.

When I do `JSON.parse(data).projects[0].name` I have "New Pretender",
when I do `JSON.parse(data).projects[0].relatedTo[0]` I have undefined

I have tried few different syntaxes but none of them was working...
The structure is like this :

```
{
    "projects": [{
        "name":"New Pretender", 
        "shortDescription":"A love coach not like the others", 
        "year":"2016",
        "description":"An interactive game/fiction design object you can play with a boob-shaped joystick. Talk about manipulation and other things.", 
        "relatedTo": ["ecriture", "rhetorique", "jeu"]
    }, {
        "name":"Pénombre", 
        "shortDescription":"A game about go out", 
        "year":"2016",
        "description":"This game invites th player to experiment what it is to be alone in a huge world, not knowing where you have to go.", 
        "relatedTo": ["jeu", "carte"]
    }, {
        "name":"Bodmer Lab", 
        "shortDescription":"A generative book based on Martin Bodmer' Faust collection", 
        "year":"2016",
        "description":"This is a book made with a lots of digitized old books that are in the Martin Bodmer huge collection.", 
        "relatedTo": ["ecriture", "generatif"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `JSON.parse(data).projects[0].relatedTo` ?

Comment: The object you are accessing doesn't seem to have the structure you expect it to.

Comment: The result is `undefined`, however the result of `JSON.parse(data).projects[0].relatedTo[0]` is `TypeError: jsonData.projects[0].relatedTo is undefined`

Comment: Please post text, not an image.

Comment: I have edited it (I used `<code>` but I haven't be able to format the text correcty)

Answer (score 0):

Given the structure above, `projects[0].relatedTo[0]` would return `ecriture`. I do not see anything incorrect with your syntax. However, it seems as if you may not be looking at the object you think you are.

Is it possible `projects[0]` is pointing to a project that does not have any relations (i.e. an empty list)? This would result in undefined when trying to access `relatedTo[0]`. I'd encourage you to check out what `relatedTo` is, and even what `projects[0]` is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "However, it seems as if you may not be looking at the object you think you are." ? The json file is exactly like in the image, it was written by me and is accessed locally

Comment: It is not possible that projects[0] is pointd to a project that does not have any relations. When I console.log `projects[0]`, the "relatedTo" array does not appear, I have the 4 other properties but not this one. I still don't understand why (I am new to json)

Answer (score 0):

I feel so idiotic... I forgot that I have duplicated my json file so I was just calling a file in which the property doesn't exist. I changed the path and now it's ok.